# Error in magento admin panel : Source model "marketplace/catalog_product_attribute_status" not found for attribute "product_status"

Tags: magento-1.8

I am getting error as

> 'Source model "marketplace/catalog_product_attribute_status" not found
>   for attribute "product_status"'

after click on product in manage product section of magento admin panel.

Does anyone has gone through same error.

**Solution : Disabled the module from admin panel and also from xml file resolved the issue**

Answer (score 0):

Check following file exist or not. If not create one. If make sure your custom module active.

```
app/code/[local OR community]/Vendor/Marketplace/Model/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Status.php
```

```
class Marketplace_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Status extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all attribute options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Yes'),
                    'value' => 1
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No'),
                    'value' => 0
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use config'),
                    'value' => 2
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sohel for reply. I have disabled the extension for marketplace which causing this issue and resolved the issue.